# How can I change my [vuetify.js] icon color in v-alert

Tags: vuetify.js

Am having trouble trying to change the icon color in v-alert .

```
<v-alert
        v-model="alert1"
        dismissible
        width="300px"
      
        style="
          position: fixed;
          left: 50%;
          bottom: 50px;
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          margin: 0 auto;
          z-index: 1000001 !important;
          color:white;
        "
        icon="mdi-alert"
        color="orange"
      >
        {{ alertData1 }}
      </v-alert>
```

Comment: you have `color:white;` in your style and `color="orange"` as a prop.  try just using one.

Comment: What color do you want for the icon? and for which icon, close icon or warning icon?

Comment: Yap,I want to change the warning Icon`s color

Comment: @yoduh the color white is for the text inside the alert and the color orange is the background color of alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention which color you want to give to the alert icon.
However, instead of using CSS, you can simply use the **dark** prop which will make the text and icon both white.

**Working demo-**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      alert1: true,
      alertData1: "My Alert"
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.1/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.1/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-alert
        v-model="alert1"
        dismissible
        dark
        width="300px"
        style="
          position: fixed;
          left: 10%;
          top: 50px;
          margin: 0 auto;
          z-index: 1000001 !important;
        "
        icon="mdi-alert"
        color="orange"
      >
        {{ alertData1 }}
      </v-alert>

  </v-app>
</div>
```

And if you want to give a specific color to the warning icon only then you can use custom CSS. For example-

```
.mdi-alert {
  color: red !important;
}
```

**Working demo-**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      alert1: true,
      alertData1: "My Alert"
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.mdi-alert {
  color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.1/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.1/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-alert
        v-model="alert1"
        dismissible
        dark
        width="300px"
        style="
          position: fixed;
          left: 10%;
          top: 50px;
          margin: 0 auto;
          z-index: 1000001 !important;
        "
        icon="mdi-alert"
        color="orange"
      >
        {{ alertData1 }}
      </v-alert>

  </v-app>
</div>
```